# Inside tmux, docker commands won't work without sudo

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am trying to run docker without sudo on ubuntu 16.04.
I followed the Linux post-installation instructions on the docker website:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

I rebooted and then ran

```
docker ps
```

this error still appears:

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon
>   socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get
>   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.37/containers/json: dial unix
>   /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

the weird thing is if i ssh from my machine to itself the command is executed correctly.
when i run the command from tty it also works correctly.

**edit:**

output of ls -lah /var/run/docker.sock:

```
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Aug  9 11:22 /var/run/docker.sock
```

output of id:

```
uid=1000(uname) gid=1000(uname) groups=1000(uname),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),128(sambashare),999(docker)
```

what could have gone wrong?
thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you include in the post the output of 'ls -lah /var/run/docker.sock' ?

Comment: @Neekoy added the command's output

Comment: The docker socket is alright. Can you also run 'id' and paste the output?

Comment: Can you run `groups` command and see if `docker` is in the list?

Comment: @Neekoy i added the id output

Comment: @byrnedo docker is in the groups list

Comment: What do you mean by `the weird thing is if i ssh from my machine to itself the command is executed correctly`? In which scenario does it not work exactly @unameuname?

Comment: @byrnedo does not work when i use the terminal directly.
works when i use tty or when i use ssh user@localhost .

Answer (score 38, accepted):

So apparently the problem was the tmux shell.

The problem occurs when an account is added to the docker group, while still having at least one tmux session open. closing all tmux sessions solves the problem [the group accounts will now be updated in the next session].

solution:

1. kill tmux:

> pkill -f tmux

2. open tmux and test docker:

> docker run hello-world

now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

If you initially ran Docker CLI commands using sudo before adding your user to the docker group you may get this error the you need to remove the ~/.docker/ directory (it is recreated automatically, but any custom settings are lost), or change its ownership and permissions using the following commands:

```
$ sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R
$ sudo chmod g+rwx "/home/$USER/.docker" -R
```

Comment: ~/.docker/ does not exist in my filesystem