# Why I can use docker in the terminal but not inside tmux?

Tags: docker, tmux

I am trying to use docker on a remote machine.

When I do `docker ps` I got a list of the running dockers

However when I do `tmux new -s Mysession` and I enter a tmux session, and I try to do the same `docker ps` I got

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Note: I know that normally I can solve this with https://stackoverflow.com/a/48569858/4451521 . Unfortunately I can not do that since my user is not in the sudoers group.
And I am actually asking why it works outside tmux and not inside

Comment: I found an answer to this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52136505/4451521